# Cookies always expire instanlty

Tags: javascript

Simple cookie documenting, i have 7 checkboxes, kp1-kp7 setCookies, each time you click on some of them, cookie is created. The problem is that when i close my browser, and reopen page (locally), cookies disappear, they are not there.
When i click on checkbox, and create cookie, he is created [picture to prove it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPAq0.png)

[part of html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1VxB.png)

```
window.onload = function(){

  if(document.cookie.length != 0){
    var nizKolacica = document.cookie.split("; ");
    var nizVrednostiKolacica = nizKolacica.split("=");

    // 0 - c1tip
    // 1 - tekst / cb
    // 2 - c2tip
    // 3 - tekst / cb

    if(nizVrednostiKolacica[1] == "tekst" || nizVrednostiKolacica.length == 0){
      document.getElementById("kp1").checked = true;
    }else{
       document.getElementById("kp1").checked = false;
    }

    if(nizVrednostiKolacica[3] == "tekst" || nizVrednostiKolacica.length == 0){
      document.getElementById("kp2").checked = true;
    }else{
       document.getElementById("kp2").checked = false;
    }

    if(nizVrednostiKolacica[5] == "tekst" || nizVrednostiKolacica.length == 0){
      document.getElementById("kp3").checked = true;
    }else{
       document.getElementById("kp3").checked = false;
    }

    if(nizVrednostiKolacica[7] == "tekst" || nizVrednostiKolacica.length == 0){
      document.getElementById("kp4").checked = true;
    }else{
       document.getElementById("kp4").checked = false;
    }

    if(nizVrednostiKolacica[9] == "tekst" || nizVrednostiKolacica.length == 0){
      document.getElementById("kp5").checked = true;
    }else{
       document.getElementById("kp5").checked = false;
    }

    if(nizVrednostiKolacica[12] == "tekst" || nizVrednostiKolacica.length == 0){
      document.getElementById("kp6").checked = true;
    }else{
       document.getElementById("kp6").checked = false;
    }

    if(nizVrednostiKolacica[12] == "tekst" || nizVrednostiKolacica.length == 0){
      document.getElementById("kp7").checked = true;
    }else{
       document.getElementById("kp7").checked = false;
    }

  }
}

var kp1 = false;
var kp2 = false;
var kp3 = false;
var kp4 = false;
var kp5 = false;
var kp6 = false;
var kp7 = false;

function kp1SetCoockie(){

    kp1 = !kp1;
    if(kp1){
      document.cookie = "c1tip=tekst;expires=Sun, 25 Jun 2017 8:00:00 UTC";
    }else{
      document.cookie ="c1tip=cb";
    }
}

function kp2SetCoockie(){
  kp2 = !kp2;
  if(kp2){
    document.cookie = "c2tip=tekst;max-age=3600";
  }else{
    document.cookie ="c2tip=cb";
  }
}

function kp3SetCoockie(){
  kp3 = !kp3;
  if(kp3){
    document.cookie = "c3tip=tekst;max-age=3600; path=/";
  }else{
    document.cookie ="c3tip=cb";
  }
}

function kp4SetCoockie(){
  kp4 = !kp4;
  if(kp4){
    document.cookie = "c4tip=tekst;max-age=3600; path=/";
  }else{
    document.cookie ="c4tip=cb";
  }
}

function kp5SetCoockie(){
  kp5 = !kp5;
  if(kp5){
    document.cookie = "c5tip=tekst;max-age=3600; path=/";
  }else{
    document.cookie ="c5tip=cb";
  }
}

function kp6SetCoockie(){
  kp6 = !kp6;
  if(kp6){
    document.cookie = "c6tip=tekst;max-age=3600; path=/";
  }else{
    document.cookie ="c6tip=cb";
  }
}

function kp7SetCoockie(){
  kp7 = !kp7;
  if(kp7){
    document.cookie = "c7tip=tekst;max-age=3600; path=/";
  }else{
    document.cookie ="c7tip=cb";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a expiration date

```
  var date = new Date();
  date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days*24*60*60*1000));
  var expires = date.toUTCString();
  document.cookie = name + "=" + value + "; expires=" + expires + "; path=/";
```

Edit: Are you sure that this does not work??

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            console.log(document.cookie);

            var date = new Date();
            date.setTime(date.getTime() + (1*24*60*60*1000));
            var expires = date.toUTCString();

            console.log("test=test; expires=" + expires + "; path=/");
            document.cookie = "test=test; expires=" + expires + "; path=/";

            console.log(document.cookie);
        </script>
    </head>
</html>
```

I just tested this and it is working. The only thing that was not working was my firefox extension which told me that there are 0 cookies. But when I used console.log(document.cookie); it printed me the cookie!

What exactly should your else do here?

```
if(kp3){
    document.cookie = "c3tip=tekst;max-age=3600; path=/";
  }else{
    document.cookie ="c3tip=cb";
  }
```

Comment: Oh I missed the first one... hmm, define the path?

Comment: Tried it in kp3:D

Comment: yeah, but not expires in combination with path :)

Comment: just did, didn't help

Comment: I just did, it does same thing as mine, creates cookie, but when I refresh, it  cant find it.. I've just tried with local storage, same thing.

That line of code is supposed to update value, so it changes on every click, from text to cb and other way around

Comment: Tested with another browser so far?

Comment: Ok, local storage actually works, it doesn't show me that there are any, but when i call it to print it, it does, so, i guess ill work with that

Comment: Okay strange, have you tried my simple example too, one time? And looking in the console, if the cookie is still there after restart?

Comment: I've just put it on actual site, and it works.. sorry for the trobule, and thanks for answering :)

Comment: Yes, i did try it